# Why does my Pentium(R) Dual Core, running ubuntu 12.04 LTS block access to system admin. functions?

Tags: ubuntu

Since upgrading my computer version of ubuntu some weeks back I been experiencing several issues, most notably:

1. System will not shutdown.  It responds normally to the drop down command, but then just cycles back up.
2. I cannot find, let alone access a comprehensive applications menu.
3. I cannot open a command line window for setting values such as a java path.
   Pressing <kbd>ctrl</kbd>/<kbd>del</kbd> <kbd>F1</kbd> does bring me to a command window.  But I'm confronted by a login prompt, and it will not accept my user name and password.

Any solutions offered to these issues will be appreciated.

Comment: The title should be re-worded. This has nothing to do with your CPU, nor admin access. It's just a messed up upgrade.

Answer (score 2):

There is only one thing I can think of.
You can back up your /home config files (basically everything that starts with a . (dot)).

Once you are sure that the backup is DONE **AND** OK, remove all the . (dot) files from your home.
Next time you log-in, Ubuntu will welcome you with a new clean desktop.
Now first of all, check if things are working again.. or not.

If they indeed do, you can start copying back your files, but ONLY what you need.
Like the Firefox profile of yours, Thunderbird if you have one. And such.
But nothing more. Don't copy *everything* back.
If anything, do it gradually.